# javascript regex matchAll

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does it return true for

```
  const regex = /\+\+\+\+/gm;

  let test = `+++`

  if (test.matchAll(regex)) {
    alert(true)
  }
  else {
    alert(false)
  }
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). Have you tried putting `\`+++\`.matchAll(/\+\+\+\+/gm)` into the console to see what it evaluates as?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

> The matchAll() method returns an iterator of all results matching a
> string against a regular expression, including capturing groups. - MDN

So if there is a match or not, It will return an iterator object.

In your case, there will not be a match and will return an iterator and it is considered as a `truthy` value.

You can get all result and collect into an array and then check the length of that array to check for the match as:

```
const matches = [...test.matchAll(regex)];
```

**If there is no match then `matches` will be empty array**

```js
const regex = /\+\+\+\+/gm;

let test = `+++`;

const matches = [...test.matchAll(regex)];
console.log(matches);
if (matches.length) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

**If there is a match then matches will be an array of matches**

```js
const regex = /\+\+\+\+/gm;

let test = `++++`;

const matches = [...test.matchAll(regex)];
console.log(matches);
if (matches.length) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`matchAll` returns an iterator, which, when coerced to a boolean, is `true`.

Perhaps you meant [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)?

```js
const regex = /\+\+\+\+/gm;

let test = `+++`

if (test.match(regex)) {
  console.log(true)
} else {
  console.log(false)
}
```

Although for this purpose, [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is better:

```js
const regex = /\+\+\+\+/gm;

let test = `+++`

if (regex.test(test)) {
  console.log(true)
} else {
  console.log(false)
}
```